# Common root of two polynomials and their $\gcd$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots, extension-field

Could someone help me on the following question?

> Let $F$ be an extension of a field $K$. Let $P_{1}(X),P_{2}(X)\in K[X]$ and $\alpha\in F$. Show that $\alpha$ it is a common root of $P_{1}(X)$ and $P_{2}(X)$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a root of greatest common divisor of $P_{1}(X)$ and $P_{2}(X)$.

($\Rightarrow$) Just note that greatest common divisor of $P_{1}(X),P_{2}(X)$ is $P_{1}(X)Q_{1}(X)+P_{2}(X)Q_{2}(X)$.

($\Leftarrow$) Here I am in doubt. If $\alpha$ is the root of the greatest common divisor, then $P_{1}(\alpha)Q_{1}(\alpha)+P_{2}(\alpha)Q_{2}(\alpha)=0$. From here I do not know how to conclude that alpha is not the root of  $P_{1}(X)$ and $P_{2}(X)$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of a divisor of $P_i$, it already is a root of $P_i$.

Comment: But as I write that it cannot be a root of $Q_{i}$?  It is not so clear to me

Comment: A common divisor is a divisor. So is the greatest common divisor.

Comment: @user899489 You don't need the $Q_{1,2}$ form for the reverse implication. Just use that any root of a divisor is a root of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($\Rightarrow$) Just note that greatest common divisor of $P_{1}(X),P_{2}(X)$ **can be written** as $P_{1}(X)Q_{1}(X)+P_{2}(X)Q_{2}(X)$.

($\Leftarrow$) If $\alpha$ is the root of the greatest common divisor, then, since it divides $P_1$ and $P_2$, we get that $\alpha$ is also a root of $P_1$ and $P_2$. (More precisely, if a polynomial $Q$ divides a polynomial $P$, then we can write $P=QR$, and $Q(\alpha)=0$ implies $P(\alpha)=0$.)